# How do I print out a string "this is a string of words" as argv[1] in C?

Tags: c, quotes

```
./a.out "this is a string of words"
```

```
char *str = argv[1];
printf("%s\n", str);
```

How do I manipulate this so that it accounts for the spaces?  Right now I am only able to print "this" because the white space prevents the rest of the argument from printing!

---

OK so I am going to assume it is my own system... something maybe with the shell or something.

I have tried all of these and none are working:

```
printf("%s\n", str);

printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

while (*p != '\0')
{
    printf("%c", *p);
    p++;   
}
```

Comment: What you showed is technically correct, so it has to be a problem with your dev environment not parsing the parameter correctly, or your command line environment not passing the parameter correctly. The code you showed is fine as-is.

Comment: I just tried another OS and I'm getting the same thing, so I don't think it is the dev environment.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you showed. It has to be elsewhere. If the command line interpreter accepts quoted parameters, and your compiler's RTL parses quoted parameters correctly, then `argv[1]` will point at a single string with whitespace preserved, as expected. `printf("%s")` prints everything up to the null terminator, so if the output is only the first word (check `argc` and debug inspect `argv`) then the quoted parameter is not being processed correctly before it reaches your code. If you have the same problem on multiple OS then your dev environment is likely the culprit.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which OS platform(s) are you using? What is an `.out` file anyway?

Comment: @RemyLebeau `a.out` is the default output of several linkers on *nix systems, including, I believe, GCC.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I believe `a.out` is the default output filename for gcc's linker (at least it is on OSX). But mac has no issues with quoted arguments that I'm aware of.

Comment: @user2470057 This codes works as expected compiled on Debian linux with GCC 4.7.2, what OS are you using, and is this your actual code that's not working?

Comment: I'm in fedora 19 compiling with gcc using -ansi -pedantic -Wall and running in a bash terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the completed code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        char *str = argv[1];  // Not really necessary, but consistent with the question
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then there is very little chance on a Unix-like system with a standard shell of seeing what you claim to be seeing. Given that source code in `e1.c` and having compiled `e1` (I use `make`, so I never get a program `a.out`), I can run:

```
$ ./e1 "This is a string of words"
This is a string of words
$
```

as would be expected.  You could get just `This` if you used some obscure invocation:

```
$ ./e1 $(echo "This is a string of words")
This
$ ./e1 “This is a string of words”
“This
$
```

The second of these commands uses Unicode U+201C ('`“`', LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and U+201D ('`”`', RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) in place of U+0022 ('`"`', QUOTATION MARK). The shell does not recognize these as shell quotes, so you get to see the open quote and the word 'This' as the first argument to the command. This is, however, pretty improbable as an explanation of your problem.

So, either the code I deduced is not close enough to the full code you have (please provide the code for an SSCCE — [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), or you've not told us the full story of how you are invoking the program.  Which shell are you using?  Which platform are you on?
(I tested on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, with GCC 4.8.2, just for the record, but this is not going to be compiler sensitive. I'm using `bash` as provided with Mac OS X. I don't have any odd settings in `bash` that could mess up the interpretation of words, but if you weren't seeing the double quotes in front of `This` in the echoed output, … well, I'm at a loss to explain how you got the output you claim to get.)

Comment: Jonathan,  You keep saying "claim"... I wouldn't be here if I was seeing any other result.

Comment: The absence of a complete program, example output copied and pasted, and a description of the environment you are using means you claim to be seeing something unexpected. I'm counter-claiming that any Unix-like system I can think of (and I've worked on a large number over the years) would not demonstrate the behaviour you claim to see. I have provided complete code and sample output to back up my contention. You have to take my word for it that I see what I claim to see. Other people seem to agree with me because it jibes with their experience, whereas what you are seeing does not.

Comment: If you want to, you can consider my 'answer' to be a formatted counter-question that's simply to big to fit into comments — a request to you to provide more details and the complete program you are running. When you've provided a convincing demonstration and the information requested, people will hustle to try and reproduce what you claim to see. People have already reproduced what I claim to see — see the comments. (You could take the code I showed, compile it and run it on your machine in the same way that I showed it running on mine. If you get different results, I want to know!)

Comment: Another demonstration would be a program like this: `#include <stdio.h>` and then `int main(int argc, char **argv) { for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) printf("%d: <<%s>>\n", i, argv[i]); return 0; }`. This will print each of the arguments, including the program name, on standard output, with the text enclosed in angle brackets `<<...>>`. Showing the output from that program when run with your quoted string argument will tell me a lot.

Comment: Hey Jonathan,

I am just going to assume it is a bug in my system somewhere as I have asked others in my class if they are getting the same issue.  They aren't.  Thank you for your explanation, it has given me enough to know that it is my computer and not something wrong with the logic of my program.

Comment: I'd love to know how you've managed to get to that state, though. At the moment, my best guess is that you're running your own home-brew shell and it doesn't handle double quotes correctly, but you'd remember if that was the case, and you'd probably be getting a double quote in the output, like '`"This`'. Have you tried running `/bin/bash -l` to start a new login session, and then run your program, for example? You now mention Fedora 19, using `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall` and `bash` in a terminal. Very odd; very unexpected for the stated environment. I hate to ask, but when did you last reboot?